# Stripe payment tunnel with different subscriptions

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I work with django/python and stripe API pip package

I am looking to create a stripe payment tunnel allowing me to bill a basket in one go that can contain :

- Single Purchase items
- One or more subscriptions which may have a different price and frequency

The customer must be able to cancel one subscription without canceling the other which would be subscribed at the same time.

I'm having trouble understanding the payment tunnel, which method I should use in the API

I need to be guided through the broad outlines of the process

For now I have:

- retrieved or created the client
- retrieved or created the article
- created a unique price (price_id)

Checkout gave bad results because there cannot be several subscription type items with different frequency in checkout

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear, but I believe you're currently implementing Stripe Checkout in `subscription` mode.

> created a unique price (price_id)

It's worth mentioning that if you're using variable prices, you shouldn't create a Price object every single time - you should use the `price_data` array to create a Price inline with your Checkout Session, like this:

```
line_items=[{
      'price_data': {
        'currency': 'usd',
        'product_data': {
          'name': product_name,
        },
        'unit_amount': 2000,
        'recurring':{'interval':'month'},
      },
      'quantity': 1,
    }],
```

> One or more subscriptions which may have a different price and frequency

That is simply impossible to handle with Stripe Subscriptions natively. You would need to have one Subscription per interval.

Here's what I would suggest:
-Use Checkout in `subscription` mode to create one Subscription.
This will return a Subscription object (`sub_`) with a Payment method object (`pm_`) and a Customer object (`cus_`).

-Create more Subscriptions with this Payment Method* and Customer from the backend:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create
You can use `price_data` here too, but not `product_data`.

*You can set the Payment Method as default on the Subscription or the Customer (after which it will automatically apply to new Subscriptions):
-Set the Payment Method as default on the Customer:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-default_payment_method
-Set the Payment Method as default on the new Susbcription:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-default_payment_method

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, my customer ask me to change bank system so i can try your code, but thanks